# Array from string including special characters

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, character

How can I make an array from a string and include special characters as standalone values?

```
var str = "Hi, how are you doing?";
var TxtArray = str.split(" ");
```

The output will be:

```
Hi,,how,are,you,doing?
```

Now I want the output to be:

```
Hi,,,how,are,you,doing,?
```

Notice the (,) and (?) are separated in the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `match` instead of `split`, you can then use a regular expression that matches word characters (`\w`), OR matches your special characters (`[,?]`) to get your desired result:

```js
var str = "Hi, how are you doing?";
console.log(str.match(/\w+|[,?]/g))
```

Comment: When answers solve your problem, consider marking them as Accepted to indicate that your issue is resolved :)